# Modified selection sort that selects the biggest number then swap to the end

Tags: c++, arrays

I have code here. I need to select the largest value in array and swap it to the end. please help me.

1.The inner loop is to find the index of the largest item inside the unsorted region.

2.The outer loop is to swap the largest item with the rightmost unsorted item, and then the right most unsorted item becomes the newest sorted item.

3.The array started as one big unsorted region; each inner loop iteration move one unsorted item to become a sorted item.

4.The number of comparisons is the same as the standard bubble sort, however, the number of swaps are reduced to no more than once per inner loop and no more than n times for the entire sort.

```js
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
  
void swap(int *xp, int *yp)  
{  
    int temp = *xp;  
    *xp = *yp;  
    *yp = temp;  
}  
  
void selectionSort(int arr[], int n)  
{  
    int i, j, max_idx;  
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)  
    {  
        max_idx = i;  
        for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)  
        if (arr[j] < arr[max_idx])  
            max_idx = j;  
  
        swap(&arr[max_idx], &arr[i]);  
    }  
}  
  
void printArray(int arr[], int size)  
{  
    int i;  
    for (i=0; i < size; i++)  
        cout << arr[i] << " ";  
    cout << endl;  
}  
  
int main()  
{  
    int arr[] = {64, 25, 12, 22, 11};  
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);  
    selectionSort(arr, n);  
    cout << "Sorted array: \n";  
    printArray(arr, n);  
    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the code mentioned above, you are finding the smallest element in the array and swapping it to the leftmost unsorted index.

```
void selectionSort(int arr[], int n)  
{  
    int i, j, max_idx;  
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)  
    {  
        max_idx = i;  
        for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)  
        if (arr[j] < arr[max_idx])  
            max_idx = j;  

        swap(&arr[max_idx], &arr[i]);  
    }  
}
```

Modify the above code to:

```
void selectionSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i, j, max_idx;
    for (i = n - 1; i >0; i--)//starting from rightof array and decrementing

    {
        max_idx = i;//selecting max_idx as rightmost unsorted element index
        for (j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) //inloop iterating from 0 to rightmost unsorted index and fiding maximum element
            if (arr[j] > arr[max_idx]) 
                max_idx = j;

        swap(&arr[max_idx], &arr[i]); //swamping maximum element with rightmost unsorted element
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's modify the selectionSort() function to fulfill your requirements:

```c
void selectionSort(int arr[], int n)  
{  
    int i, j, max_idx, left_most_sorted_idx;  

    // set the left_most_sorted_idx, initially no Sorted elements, so set the value to `n`
    left_most_sorted_idx = n;

    // loop over the unsorted array 
    for (i = 0; i < left_most_sorted_idx; i++)  
    {  
        max_idx = i;
        // pick the max element of unsorted array 
        for (j = 0; j < left_most_sorted_idx; j++)  
        if (arr[j] > arr[max_idx])
        {
            max_idx = j;
        }

        // move left_most_sorted_idx to one index left 
        left_most_sorted_idx--;

        // swap the max value to the new the left_most_sorted_idx
        swap(&arr[max_idx], &arr[left_most_sorted_idx]);

    }  
}
```